# Exception: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index') c#

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error on some of my while loops when I try to replace some of my variables.

Below is the code for my main class:

```
int i = 0;

                            while (ships.Read())
                            {

                                product_id = ships.GetString(0);
                                unit_price = ships.GetDecimal(1);
                                currency = ships.GetString(2);

                                model.Events[i].Event_params.Product_id = product_id;
                                model.Events[i].Event_params.Unit_price = unit_price;
                                model.Events[i].Event_params.Currency = currency;
                                i++;


                            }
```

And below is my class structure to get and set the data.

```
 public class InsiderCRMAPI
{
    [JsonProperty("users")]
    public Collection<UserModel> User = new Collection<UserModel>();

    [JsonProperty("events")]
    public Collection<EventModel> Events = new Collection<EventModel>();
}
public class EventModel
{
    [JsonProperty("event_name")]
    public string Event_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("event_params")]
    public ProductModel Event_params { get; set; } = new ProductModel();

    [JsonProperty("taxonomy")]
    public Collection<TaxModel> Taxonomy = new Collection<TaxModel>();


}
public class ProductModel
{
    [JsonProperty("product_id")]
    public string Product_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit_price")]
    public decimal Unit_price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom")]
    public CustomProdModel Custom { get; set; } = new CustomProdModel();

}
```

Any help with how to fix the issue or find what's causing the exception would be great!

Comment: I would say at some point `i` becomes larger than `model.Events` length

Comment: Can you include the code where `Model.Events` is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you try to get the ith element (first, second, ...) but your not in a array where you already defined the size and every "cells" are available. You're in a collection and that collection is empty so if you try to get the first element it just crashed because there is not.

You should build your object and `Add` it to the collection:

```
        model.Events.Add(new EventModel()
        {
            Event_params = new ProductModel()
            {
                Product_id = product_id,
                Unit_price = unit_price,
                Currency = currency
            }
        });
```

Comment: How do you know it is empty? OP has not shown where that is being constructed.

Comment: I assumed it was the "Events" property in the InsiderCRMAPI class. He didn't show "model" was from that type but since it was the only class left...

Comment: That's just a class definition, you can't tell anything about how `model` was modified in the program.

Comment: That why I said I was assuming it. His index begin to 0 so I guessed it was the first time he was using it. I may be totally wrong but I think, from what he showed, it is the issue he has.

Comment: You're probably right but it's not possible to tell for sure. I don't see anything that says it fails on index 0.

Comment: Perfect, that solved the problem! Thanks!